# What is a "semi-monotonic" function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, order-theory

In the java Math class, the outputs of some methods are described as "semi monotonic".

for example:

```
/** 
    Returns the base 10 logarithm of a {@code double} value.
    ...
    Results must be semi-monotonic.
 */

public static double log10(double a) {
    return StrictMath.log10(a);
}
```

I'm familiar with monotonic functions, but what does this mean?

Comment: Semi-monotonic is not a mathematical term.  It is a Java thing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999255/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-semi-monotonic has a few more details, but no answer.

Comment: Yes, I read that and googled it, but couldn't find anything

Comment: The [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) says that methods are semi-monotonic if "whenever the mathematical function is non-decreasing, so is the floating-point approximation, likewise, whenever the mathematical function is non-increasing, so is the floating-point approximation."

Comment: mrp Ok, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

@mrp directs us to the
[Math library](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html)
documentation on this java-specific term, which explains that
**semi-monotonic** is a notion describing how certain
[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
functions relate to an underlying mathematical function that is
[monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function):

> semi-monotonic: whenever the mathematical function is non-decreasing, so is the floating-point approximation ...

---

Consider this pair of logarithm functions:

- [StrictMath.log10](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StrictMath.html#log10(double))
- [Math.log10](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double))

The "strict" spec is:

> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value. Special cases:

- If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.
- If the argument is positive infinity, then the result is positive infinity.
- If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.
- If the argument is equal to 10n for integer n, then the result is n. In particular, if the argument is 1.0 (100), then the result is positive zero.

OTOH the `Math` spec copies that verbatim, and then weakens the
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
on the return value by appending:

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic.

So an Intel FPU or other implementation method
might possibly make significand's final bit a random boolean.
But when using such a method within the JVM,
the overall implementation must ensure that significand, including that final
[ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place),
offers monotonic FP results.
This is for consistency with the underlying mathematical function
which is itself monotone.